# Outlook "Attach debugger" not available

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am creating an Outlook Add-in using Office js libraries. I was using the option to attach the debugger to debug my javascript application. But it seems that after an Outlook update the option is no longer available. I have tried reinstalling Office but dit not help. Also i created a new Add In with the default functionality and this has no option to attach the debugger. When i click with the right mouse I see no options. Do i have to enable it in some new way ? Has somebody else seen this problem ?

Comment: Which editor are you trying to debug with?

Comment: I was using Visual Studio via the option in Outlook "attach debugger". But is seems that this option is no long available after an update of Office. But i am not realy sure if it was the update that caused the disappearance of the option

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with Office 365 version 16.0.11629 and Windows 10 version 1903, Office Add-ins running on Office 365 for Windows will use a Microsoft Edge WebView as the runtime.

The Microsoft Edge WebView performs much better than Internet Explorer and features enhanced compliance with modern browser standards including support of the full set of HTML 5 and ECMAScript 2015+.

We recommend that you download the [Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9mzbfrmz0mnj?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) for debugging.

[link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/)

Comment: Hello, 
I'm running Office Professional Plus 2016 and when I try to attach the VSCode debugger (for yo + generator office outlook add-in) it says Outlook is not supported. Is there a workaround to get it working ?

Comment: It would be great if you added this to the documentation. Ive been trying for hours to start debugging. For me it should be included in this section of the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/test-debug-office-add-ins